# Cannot load image with flutter image_editor_pro

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro). But I seem to be missing something. This is my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomePage().xMaterialApp();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File _image = File("assets/images/butterfly.jpg");

  Future<void> getimageditor() =>
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ImageEditorPro(
          appBarColor: Colors.blue,
          bottomBarColor: Colors.blue,
        );
      })).then((geteditimage) {
        if (geteditimage != null) {
          setState(() {
            _image = geteditimage;
          });
        }
      }).catchError((er) {
        print(er);
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition(
            condtion: _image == null,
            isTue: 'Open Editor'.text().xRaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getimageditor();
              },
            ).toCenter(),
            isFalse: Image.file(_image).toCenter())
        .xScaffold(
            appBar: 'Image Editor Pro example'.xTextColorWhite().xAppBar(),
            floatingActionButton:
                Icons.add.xIcons().xFloationActiobButton(color: Colors.red));
  }
}

Widget condition({bool condtion, Widget isTue, Widget isFalse}) {
  return condtion ? isTue : isFalse;
}
```

error: `Cannot open file, path = 'assets/images/butterfly.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`.

How am I supposed to load an image with this?
I even tried to use `Image` from the get go. But no result. Maybe I am doing the `File` to `Image` conversion wrong?

**Update 1: **

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final image = Image.asset('assets/images/butterfly.jpg');

  Future<void> getimageditor() =>
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ImageEditorPro(
          appBarColor: Colors.blue,
          bottomBarColor: Colors.blue,
        );
      })).then((geteditimage) {
        if (geteditimage != null) {
          setState(() {
            image = geteditimage; // shows error asking to make the field not final
          });
        }
      }).catchError((er) {
        print(er);
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition(
            condtion: image == null,
            isTue: 'Open Editor'.text().xRaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getimageditor();
              },
            ).toCenter(),
            isFalse: Image.file(image).toCenter()) //The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.
        .xScaffold(
            appBar: 'Image Editor Pro example'.xTextColorWhite().xAppBar(),
            floatingActionButton:
                Icons.add.xIcons().xFloationActiobButton(color: Colors.red));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your asset directories to your pubspec.yaml.

For example:

```yaml
dependencies:
  ...

dev_dependencies:
  ...

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
```

Then you can read the file as an image like so:

```dart
final image = Image.asset('assets/images/butterfly.jpg');
```

If you need to read the image as a file for the package you are trying to use, instead of coding in images, use a package like [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

For your case:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> getimageditor() =>
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ImageEditorPro(
          appBarColor: Colors.blue,
          bottomBarColor: Colors.blue,
        );
      })).then((geteditimage) {
        if (geteditimage != null) {
          setState(() {
            _image = geteditimage;
          });
        }
      }).catchError((er) {
        print(er);
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition(
            condtion: _image == null,
            isTue: 'Open Editor'.text().xRaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await getImage();
                await getimageditor();
              },
            ).toCenter(),
            isFalse: Image.file(_image).toCenter())
        .xScaffold(
            appBar: 'Image Editor Pro example'.xTextColorWhite().xAppBar(),
            floatingActionButton:
                Icons.add.xIcons().xFloationActiobButton(color: Colors.red));
  }
}

Widget condition({bool condtion, Widget isTue, Widget isFalse}) {
  return condtion ? isTue : isFalse;
}
```

Comment: yes assets are added.What I dont get is how to load image using a File type. I'm talking about this lin `File _image = File("assets/images/butterfly.jpg");`

Comment: And if I declare image as final I dont think I'll be able to use it lines like : `_image = geteditimage;`

Comment: Why do you need to read it as a file? From how you're using it, it seems like using image.asset solves your issue.

Comment: tried that but throws around `isFalse: Image.file(image).toCenter())` saying `The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.`

Comment: @FahimHoque Edited my answer to include an image picker. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: hi thanks for replying I'm getting these two errors.

`The method 'ImagePicker' isn't defined for the type '_HomePageState'.`
`Undefined name 'ImageSource'.`

Comment: @FahimHoque Did you install/import the image_picker package?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is error is to prevent the `Image.file` to read from null by setting a null check:

`_image == null ? Container() : Image.file(_image).toCenter())`

The app will build without error, and after that you can use the image editor pro to edit your image.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to pass image to editor page from image picker :

**make changes to image_editor_pro.dart file**

```
final Color appBarColor;
  final Color bottomBarColor;
  final Directory pathSave;
  final double pixelRatio;
  final File image;
  ImageEditorPro(
      {this.appBarColor,
      this.bottomBarColor,
      this.pathSave,
      this.pixelRatio,
      this.image});

    @override
  void initState() {
    timers();
    _controller.clear();
    type.clear();
    //  fontsize.clear();
    offsets.clear();
    //  multiwidget.clear();
    howmuchwidgetis = 0;
    _image = widget.image;
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Then use this code **

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:image_editor_pro/image_editor_pro.dart';

// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:firexcode/firexcode.dart';

// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomePage().xMaterialApp();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File? _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  Future<void> getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        print("images : $_image");
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> getimageditor() async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    final geteditimage =
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return ImageEditorPro(
        appBarColor: Colors.blue,
        bottomBarColor: Colors.blue,
        image: _image,
      );
    })).then((geteditimage) {
      print("image : $geteditimage");
      if (geteditimage != null) {
        setState(() {
          _image = geteditimage;
        });
      }
    }).catchError((er) {
      print(er);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition(
            // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
            condtion: _image == null,
            isTrue: 'Open Editor'.text().xRaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await getImage();
                await getimageditor();
              },
            ).toCenter(),
            isFalse:
                // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
                _image == null ? Container() : Image.file(_image!).toCenter())
        .xScaffold(
            appBar: 'Image Editor Pro example'.xTabText().xAppBar(),
            floatingActionButton:
                Icons.add.xIcons().xFloationActiobButton(color: Colors.red))
        .xRaisedButton(onPressed: () {
      getimageditor();
    });
  }
}

Widget? condition({required bool condtion, Widget? isTrue, Widget? isFalse}) {
  return condtion ? isTrue : isFalse;
}
```